# Electrical outlet Tests good but not good

Tags: receptacle

There is an outlet in my place that tests ok but when I plug in anything, it doesn't power up.  The tester I'm using is a three light tester.Actually, I've used two testers.  Both of them indicate the it is correct.  What gives??? Anyone have an idea?

Comment: It may be a broken wire or faulty back stab connection. It is possible to light the neon lamps in the tester but with a load the wiring opens. I have seen this in the past and tho problem may be in a prior outlet If part of a daisy chain.

Comment: @EdBeal that's pretty much the answer I would write.

Comment: Comment answers are a pox on SE. :) I never know whether to write basically the same thing in order to resolve the question or wait around for the commenter to do it and get credit.

Comment: Ed and Harper, Thank you for that answer.  I did not know that about those testers.  I thought those were the best thing since buttered bread.

Answer (score 1):

The three-light testers typically only draw a tiny current and usually use neon indicators that work at less than full voltage. They are good for showing a few common miswiring problems (e.g. where live and neutral have been swapped or where ground is not connected) but they are not good for showing bad connections which have a high resistance or which separate when hot.

I would turn off the breaker, verify power is off at the outlet and open it up and check the connections. The next step would be to swap the outlet with a new one or with another nearby working outlet.